# SQL - return all days of last month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a query that will return the total number of calls I received each day of last month for a queue. if no calls it will return zero for that day.  However when running this report for for December of 2013 the results are blank.  It appears to be due to the fact the query is returning the dates with the year of 2014 instead of 2013.  How can I adjust the query so the date is 12/01/2013, etc.

```
DECLARE @pMnth int,@pYr int,@pQueue varchar
SET @pMnth = '12'
SET @pYr = '2013'
SET @pQueue = 'Queue Name'
;

WITH
CTE_Days AS
 (
 SELECT DATEADD(month, @pMnth, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(GETDATE()), DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)))) as Dt
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Dt)
 FROM CTE_Days
 WHERE Dt < DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, @pMnth, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(GETDATE()), DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))))))
 )
 SELECT tbl1.Dt,ISNULL(Calls,0) AS Calls
 FROM CTE_Days tbl1

 LEFT JOIN(
SELECT CAST(clmdate AS Date) AS ClDt,COUNT(*) AS Calls
FROM dbo.tblcalls
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,clmdate) = @pYr
      AND DATEPART(mm,clmdate) = @pMnth
      AND clmqueue = @pQueue
GROUP BY CAST(clmdate AS Date) 
) tbl2 ON tbl1.Dt = tbl2.ClDt
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure what you're trying to do with all the variables, but if you want the first day of last month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)   -- < SQL 2012
SELECT DATEADD(day,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2))              -- SQL 2012
```

Last day of last month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))  -- < SQL 2012
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)       -- SQL 2012
```

In your code (assuming you're not on 2012):

```
DECLARE @pMnth int,@pYr int,@pQueue varchar
SET @pMnth = '12'
SET @pYr = '2013'
SET @pQueue = 'Queue Name'
;
WITH
CTE_Days AS
 (
 SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) as Dt
 UNION  ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Dt)
 FROM CTE_Days
 WHERE Dt < DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
 )
 SELECT tbl1.Dt,ISNULL(Calls,0) AS Calls
 FROM CTE_Days tbl1

 LEFT JOIN(
SELECT CAST(clmdate AS Date) AS ClDt,COUNT(*) AS Calls
FROM dbo.tblcalls
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,clmdate) = @pYr
      AND DATEPART(mm,clmdate) = @pMnth
      AND clmqueue = @pQueue
GROUP BY CAST(clmdate AS Date) 
) tbl2 ON tbl1.Dt = tbl2.ClDt
```

Update:

To incorporate your variables, I would change the month and year variables to strings, and replace `GETDATE()` with a date variable:

```
DECLARE @pMnth CHAR(2)
       ,@pYr CHAR(4)
       ,@pQueue VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@dt DATE

SET @pMnth = '12'
SET @pYr = '2013'
SET @pQueue = 'Queue Name'
SET @dt = CAST(@pYr+RIGHT('0'+@pMnth,2)+'01' AS DATE)

WITH
    CTE_Days AS
     (
     SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @dt)-1, 0) as Dt
     UNION  ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Dt)
     FROM CTE_Days
     WHERE Dt < DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @dt), 0))
     )
     SELECT tbl1.Dt,ISNULL(Calls,0) AS Calls
     FROM CTE_Days tbl1

     LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT CAST(clmdate AS Date) AS ClDt,COUNT(*) AS Calls
    FROM dbo.tblcalls
    WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,clmdate) = @pYr
          AND DATEPART(mm,clmdate) = @pMnth
          AND clmqueue = @pQueue
    GROUP BY CAST(clmdate AS Date) 
    ) tbl2 ON tbl1.Dt = tbl2.ClDt
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I am declaring the variables becuase this query is actually used for SSRS.  So SSRS is passing in those variables to get the data.  End Users select the Queue, Month and Year they want to run the report for.  Problem is if they select any month and last year now the data isn't returned.  Is it possible to use the new query you provided with those variables?

Comment: @user3170293 Sure thing, see updated answer, I'd create a `DATE` variable from the selected month and year, and use that in place of `GETDATE()`.